# Well deleting data from MySQL database is not being deleted, VB.Net code

Tags: mysql, vb.net

```vb
Public Class Remove_Text_Based
Public Function ParameterizedNonQueryCommand(ByRef NonQuery As String, ByVal Parameters As List(Of MySqlParameter), Optional ByVal Connection As MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection = Nothing) As Integer
    Dim comm As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(NonQuery, Connection)
    Try
        For Each param As MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter In Parameters
            comm.Parameters.Add(param)
        Next
        If comm.Connection.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then comm.Connection.Open()
        comm.Prepare()
        Return comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return CType(False, Integer)
    Finally
        comm.Connection.Close()
        comm.Dispose()
    End Try
End Function

Private Sub btnRemove_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRemove.Click
    Dim query As String = "DELETE FROM textquestion WHERE questionID = @questionID"
    Dim params As New List(Of MySqlParameter)
    params.Add(New MySqlParameter("question", 1))
    Dim conn As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection("server=localhost;user=root;password=password;database=giordydatabase")
    ParameterizedNonQueryCommand(query, params, conn)

    'error messages for unfilled boxes

    If QuestionIDBox.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter the questionID please")
    End If
    Dim submit As Integer = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to submit the user information", "Submit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
    If submit = DialogResult.No Then
        MessageBox.Show("The user information will not be sumbitted")
    ElseIf submit = DialogResult.Yes Then
        MessageBox.Show("The user information has been submitted")
    End If
End Sub
```

Above is the code that I have created to delete fields off a database, i've create a function to as well above the sub where my query to delete code. My issue is that the code doesn't show any errors in VS2013 but that when I run the code the field that I want deleted hasn't been deleted.

Comment: If there is an exception, you are throwing away all the information which *tells you* what is wrong.  Fix the Catch block to find out the error.

Comment: Done that now, apparently I need to define "@questionID", i'll get down to fixing that.

Comment: Now since I have added `MsgBox("Error: " & ex.ToString())`, I have an error in line 11 which is `Return comm.ExecuteNonQuery()`. VS2013 wants me to define `@questionID` which I spoke about earlier. Apparently I am missing a return statement.

Comment: Typo: change line to `params.Add(New MySqlParameter("questionID", 1))`. In the question your parameter name is "question" without "ID" part

Comment: I have a need problem, I added `End` below the `comm.dispose()` to get rid of the return statement warning. Also @Fabio I done was you told me to do and now I'm getting a SQL `VALUES(1)` error.

Comment: `VALUES(1)` error? Is it possible that you running some other query. Can you debug your code line by line?

Comment: I'll try debugging it line by line

Comment: Fixed it, will post the answer people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Public Class Remove_Text_Based

Public Function ParameterizedNonQueryCommand(ByRef NonQuery As String, ByVal Parameters As List(Of MySqlParameter), Optional ByVal Connection As MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection = Nothing) As Integer
    Dim comm As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(NonQuery, Connection)
    Try
        For Each param As MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter In Parameters
            comm.Parameters.Add(param)
        Next
        If comm.Connection.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then comm.Connection.Open()
        comm.Prepare()
        Return comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return CType(False, Integer)
        MsgBox("Error: " & ex.ToString())
    Finally
        comm.Connection.Close()
        comm.Dispose()
    End Try
End Function

Private Sub btnRemove_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRemove.Click
    Dim query As String = "DELETE FROM textquestion WHERE questionID = " & QuestionIDBox.Text & ""
    Dim params As New List(Of MySqlParameter)
    params.Add(New MySqlParameter("questionID", 1))
    Dim conn As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection("server=localhost;user=root;password=password;database=giordydatabase")
    ParameterizedNonQueryCommand(query, params, conn)
```